# Ninject Stopped Injecting My Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

In a base controller for MVC, I had the following injection code and it was working perfectly.

```
 [Inject]
 private INavigationRepository navigationRepository { get; set; }
 [Inject]
 private ISessionService sessionService { get; set; }
```

I do not get build errors and it shows ups in the Yellow Page of Death as "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and points to the first line of code that references navigationRepository.

I have may very few code changes since it was working and even backed those changes out but still get the error.  I can get around it with the code below but I lose injection.  Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

```
private INavigationRepository navigationRepository;
    private ISessionService sessionService;
    public BaseController()
    {
        navigationRepository = new NavigationRepository();
        sessionService = new SessionService(new VolunteerRepository());
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ninject can inject private properties but it has to be enabled.

```
new StandardKernel( new NinjectSettings() { InjectNonPublic = true })
```

But much better is not to use property injection. It should only be used in case there is no way to avoid it. E.g. if the injstance is created by some one else (AttributeFilter). Otherwise the dependencies can be set unintendedly from outside and you need the Inject attribute wich gives you a reference to the IoC container. I'd suggest to add a the dependencies to the constructor and use constructor injection.

Comment: +1 Good answer. And, by the way, thanks for the excellent work you've been doing with Ninject lately, Remo.

Comment: Second @StriplingWarrior 's comment. Also +1 this as one of the most important points about DI.

Comment: One thing I didnt get about this while holding onto prop injection is that if you have 4 things on a base class that need injection and you dont want to force them on derived classes, the answer is that you have a missing concept that should be encapsulated in a class - use that to refactor away from prop injection. IOW property injection is always always a bad idea - you're jsut not trying ahrd enough to refacotr away from it. Its jsut too easy to say "but in my case it's different - I have the special case on the planet that justifies PI's existence"

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am creating the instance in my case controller but may end up going to a global action filter.

Comment: @JohanLarsson It is intended not to be the default because I consider it a design flaw if you have to inject private properties. An IoC container should not do anything you can't do in a manually written factory.

Comment: Thanks! Also, this solution is needed even if the property as such is public, but its setter is not (like in: `public MyProp {get; protected set;}`

Answer (score 2):

Changing the properties to public worked.  I guess if it is private, Ninject can not set it.

```
[Inject]
public INavigationRepository navigationRepository { get; set; }
[Inject]
public ISessionService sessionService { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you add this as either an edit to your question or a comment on the answer please? And dont forget to indent code by 4 with CtrlK to make it look right